# Removing Cufon once it has been loaded

Tags: javascript, cufon

I know this is a bit of a bizarre one, but I am using Cufon on one of my pages, but I need to be able to turn it off for all elements if the user presses a button.

Now I was hoping there would be like a Cufon.Reset(selector) or something, but I couldnt find anything, so is there any way to turn Cufoned text back into standard text without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var RemoveCufon = function (selector) {
    $(selector).each(function (index, element) { $(element).text(BuildCufonTextString(element)); });
};

var BuildCufonTextString = function (parent) {
    var elementText = "";
    $("cufon cufontext", parent).each(function (index, element) { elementText += $(element).text(); });
    return $.trim(elementText);
};
```

Here is a manual way of doing it which works, but would like to know of anything simpler...

Answer (score 2):

Don't think so. Cufon is creating an img. So undoing it without page refresh is not possible.

You could write some script to:

- copy text(copy html tag and hide it) before Cufon is run on it
- than on button click hide cufon and show copied text element with pure text

I would suggest using @font-face rather than Cufon- works great on IE, FF, Safari. Chrome is let say 80% quality.

Check out [this website](http://webiq.co) - it is using @font-face method. Working perfectly.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about taking that route, but as it ends up I have a requirement on Cufon... I have got a manual way using the cufontext elements, but its not nice :(

Comment: @somemvcperson Why requiring Cufon? Was the issue with @font-face?

Answer (score 1):

Let say all of your H1 tags are with cufont style. To perform this you will use:

```
Cufon.replace('h1');
```

if you want to revert cufon action you can use:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    $(this).find('cufon').each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).find('cufontext').text())
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the whole process of implementing a simpler version of one of the scripts discussed here in order to get the text out of the cufontext tags.  It was working just fine:

```
var nameFromCufon = $(profileName).find('cufontext').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text())
})
```

ProfileName is the immediate parent span tag surrounding the cufon tags. Then I tried something so simple it was too obvious:
    $(profileName).text();

.text give me just the text with all the tag code stripped out.  So simple.